# Setting Background URL with Variable - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: php, css

So in my code the $image is randomised like so:

```
$image = get_rand_img('images/featured_images/csgo/');
```

if I echo `$image`, (bearing in mind I'm already inside PHP brackets) i.e:

```
echo'div id="featured-image">'
echo '<img src="/images/featured_images/dota/' . $image . '" alt="" />'
echo '</div>'
```

Then it works.

What I actually want to do, is assign this image to the div it's in

```
echo '<div id="featured-image" style="height: 267px; width: 292px">#
echo '<style="background:url('. $image .') "></style>'
echo '</div>'
```

This doesn't work. It draws the div but doesn't apply the background. I've tried various different things like `"`

What is wrong?

***EDIT***

The following code suggestions work.

```
<?php
try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpass);
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    echo 'Could not establish a connection to the database.';
}

$query = $conn->prepare('SELECT `articleid`,`title`  FROM `news_articles` WHERE  featured = 1 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1');
$array = array(
    'N'
);
$query->execute();

$results = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0);
foreach ($results as $row) {
}

$image = get_rand_img('images/featured_images/csgo/');
$title = $result['title'];
echo '<a href="index.php?viewarticle=1&articleid=' . $row . '">';?>
<div id="featured-image" style="height: 267px; width: 292px; background:url(/images/featured_images/csgo/<?php echo $image ?>)"></div>;
<?php
echo '</a>';
?>
```

Thanks guys!

Comment: Mike, you are misunderstanding the usage of variables, both answers below are correct, you need to `echo` or `print` a variable for it to actually display. You can't just put the variable there and hope it will print out. Which is why it isn't working for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things wrong here.

The `</style>` tag in `<style="background:url('. $image .') "></style>` will trigger a **Stray end tag "style"** warning in HTML source.

You also need to use PHP tagging and echoing the variable.

Sidenote: I doubt you want to use 2x `<style>` tags here, rather than using all styles set as inlined.

```
<div id="featured-image" style="height: 267px; width: 292px; background:url('<?php echo $image;?>')">
```

If this isn't what you're looking for, I'll simply delete my answer.

Edit: As per OP's comment that they're inside PHP, use and as an example:

```
$image = "image.jpg";

echo '
<div id="featured-image" style="height: 267px; width: 292px; background:url('.$image.')">
</div>
';
```

---

**Edit #2:** and some questions in here too, because I fear commenting will go on forever.

You're using what looks to be 2 paths here:

```
$image = get_rand_img('images/featured_images/csgo/');
```

and in `(/images/featured_images/<?php echo $image ?>)` which by the way, you're already in PHP here, so drop those `<?php echo` - `?>`.

You need to use the `get_rand_img()` function's path here and just the `$image` variable, not both paths.

Sidenote: It's hard to say which path you want to use here.

Do you really have a path called

`images/featured_images/csgo/images/featured_images/` - ??

- `images/featured_images/csgo/` ?? (and no slash like the one below)?
- `/images/featured_images/` ??

Only you know what that is. So I suggest you do/try either

```
$image = get_rand_img('images/featured_images/csgo/');

$image = get_rand_img('images/featured_images/');
```

Depending on which folder you want to extract the images from.

This

```
echo '<a href="index.php?viewarticle=1&articleid=' . $row . '">';?>
<div id="featured-image" style="height: 267px; width: 292px; background:url(/images/featured_images/<?php echo $image ?>)"></div>;
```

Should have thrown you an error. You have a `;?>` after `$row . '">';` and that is closing your statement and also the PHP.

So just do this:

```
echo '<a href="index.php?viewarticle=1&articleid=' . $row . '">
<div id="featured-image" style="height: 267px; width: 292px; background:url('.$image.');"></div>';
```

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Displaying errors should only be done in staging, and never production.

Comment: yeah this is the second comment of the same thing, I need to refine my question, I'm already inside PHP brackets

Comment: @MikeXero ok, well the principal still applies. Give me a minute.

Comment: @Fred-ii- see my comment attached to the OP.

Comment: @MikeXero I didn't look at your edit if you made one, but made an edit to my answer. Reload it.

Comment: @Script47 seeing their edit now, I am unsure as to what they're trying to do here exactly. Their `#` sign suggests/implies that they're probably wanting it to be clickable somewhere and using JS. No idea but my answer works given I didn't see their edit.

Comment: I'll give that a shot guys, bare with me :)

Comment: @MikeXero no problemo. What I've posted was tested and showing the image I used for a background.

Comment: @MikeXero There is one thing though and as I stated in my answer. You're using `</style>` in `<style="background:url('. $image .') "></style>` that `</style>` needs to be removed for one thing, however it's unsure if you want your page's background as the url or the div itself. If it's the div, then what I posted works (for me anyway).

Comment: `$image = get_rand_img('images/featured_images/csgo/');
$title = $result['title'];
echo '<a href="index.php?viewarticle=1&articleid=' . $row . '">';
echo '<div id="featured-image" style="height: 267px; width: 292px; background:url('.$image.')"></div>';
echo '</a>';
?>` Doesn't work, it draws the div like before but not the background-image

Comment: @MikeXero something else is causing the problem then and you need to find out why. Check for errors. I can't see what I posted would fail here. Plus, I noticed you have `get_rand_img('images/featured_images/csgo/')` but using a different folder here `<img src="/images/featured_images/dota/` so your question is a bit unclear.

Comment: Yeah sorry I have three divs all doing the same thing with different images that's all. I have closed the PHP tags and then opened them within the background:url part but it still doesn't work. I'm stumped.

Comment: @MikeXero without knowing what that function does, I won't be of any more help. Check for errors. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything, 
 as well as looking at your HTML source to see what's passing through or not. Sorry, but I did what I could with the code you provided. Good luck.

Comment: Edited the question with current standing.

Comment: @MikeXero you're using 2 paths here. One in your function and the other in here `<img src="/images/featured_images/dota/' . $image . '" alt="" />` just remove the `/images/featured_images/dota/` or set it as the path for that function. Error reporting should have kicked you back an error about this.

Comment: Don't worry about that, that was the old function as described before that posting it as an img src works fine, but using it in a background url isn't.. + I deleted it from my edit, as I said, I have Three images I'm just trying to get one working for now.

Comment: @MikeXero Reload my answer under **Edit #2**. This is my last ditch effort. Go over that entirely and read it over carefully. If that doesn't work for you, then I'll have no more hair left on my head after scratching it for so long ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to echo `$image`:

```
<style="background:url(<?php echo $image ?>) "></style>
```

Comment: Maybe expand on the answer an say why they need to echo?

Comment: @Script47 Sure. It's need to echo to actually print the value of $image.

Comment: Ok your code works, just didn't have the correct path, silly mistake.